# Union spark dataset (incrementally) with a bigger dataset in a loop

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, union

I have a list of about 10 milllion keys as list of Strings - list("xxx","yyx"......). I want to query a database to fetch records for these 10M keys in a loop as it can handle max 1 M at a time. The database returns a dataset of records. So I want to make individual calls of 1M keys and in the end union the output of all.

```
val list_len =  list.length
var start = 0
val batch_size = 1000000  // 1-Milliom
val result = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[(Array[Byte])])

while (start < list_len) {

      var end = start + batch_size
      if (end > list_len) {
        end = list_len
      }

      val df = spark.context.read("some-database")
              .load.where('key' isin list.slice(start, end))

      result = result.union(df)
      // tried performing action and caching to prevent recursive 
      // result.count
      // result.cache  

      start = start + batch_size   
}
```

But this does not work as. " result = result.union(df) " gets recursively caused . so so in the first iteration, it scans 1M records, during second 2M and so on.

Also,

I want to "execute" each iteration instantaneously rather than using lazy evaluation , because then all the calls are made to db at the same time and db responses become slow.

Comment: What is `RawBinData`? And is `list`  a list of String?

Comment: sorry fixed the post

Answer (score 0):

What you do is call the DB in the driver, creating `n` dataframe. So you can do it with simple scala, and then reduce the list of sub-result using union:

```
val list = (1 to  100) // what ever
val batchSize = 3 // 1M
val grouped = list.grouped(batchSize).toList // split list into sublist

val empty = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[(List[Byte])])

// for each group, call DB
val result = grouped.map{ subList =>

     // random code, call the DB instead
     subList.map(x => (x-1 to x+1).map(_.toByte)).toDF("data")

  }.foldLeft(empty)(_ union _) // merge all sub-result DF into one
```

### Read execution

Executing iteratively the read is another question, but here is what I know: first spark is always lazy by default, until an action is called (count, write, ...). This is because once spark start processing data, which is expected to be too big to be kept in memory, it needs to store intermediate data on disc. Read can be an exceptions because it needs to know the dataset schema. However what is done depends on the spark connector used to access data (e.g. for csv and parquet, I believe it's lazy if you give the schema and only read the files header otherwise)

1. So you can look into the the spark connector used to access your database, maybe you can trigger the call as soon as read is called. But it is not probable because it would be against spark principle, I think.
2. Otherwise you need to trigger the spark call, using an action, and keep intermediary result using cache. Something like that:

```
val result = grouped.map{ subList =>
  val subResult = spark.read.load.where(..., subList).cache
  subResult.count // minimal action to trigger read and cache
  subResult

}.foldLeft(empty)(_ union _) // merge all sub-result DF into one
```

Note: w.r.t the code in your question, be sure that the `.cache` is "in" the `subResult` variable, otherwise it won't apply:

```
val subResult = spark.[...]
subResult.cache // does nothing, cache is not an action
subResult.count // subResult doesn't contain the cache in its execution dag
```

3. An alternative, that could be better depending on your situation, would be to read and store/write each subResult into an (h)dfs dataset:

```
grouped.foreach{ subList =>
  // read and write in parquet
  spark.read.load.where(..., subList)
    .write.mode("append").parquet("hdfs://some/path")
}

// you can later read the whole (h)dfs dataset:
val everything = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://some/path")
```

In all cases above, the distribution of call will depend on the type of `grouped` and `map` or `foreach` operator. For a `List` it will be iterative, one by one call. If you want more control, you can look into scala parallel map execution, maybe using Future and ExecutionContext.

Comment: what does this do - subList.map(x => (x-1 to x+1).map(_.toByte)).toDF("data"))

Comment: I cannot call your DB, so it is just to generate some arbitrary data in the suitable type. Here, for each subList, it create a dataset containing an entry for each item in subList. And  this entry is an Array[Byte] (from x-1 to x+1 where x is the subList item)

Comment: Simply replace with your `spark.read("some-database").load.where('key' isin subList)`.

Comment: problem with this is that everything gets executed at once[lazy execution]. which then makes db responses very slow. can i perform action on the df in to "execute" each step sequentially.